# Pytesseract не видит Tesseract

Tags: python, ubuntu, tesseract

Пытаюсь распознать текст с картинки, но при запуске скрипта падает ошибка

```
raise TesseractNotFoundError()
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: /home/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/ is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.
```

Код:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('1.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

print(text)
```

Дистрибутив Ubuntu 22.04

Код запускаю в PyCharm

Сам Tesseract установлен через терминал командой:

```
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что никто не читает документацию. Присвой переменной pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd  путь к тессеракту. И проверь права доступа.

Comment: @AlexAlex Переменная присваивается на Windows, я же написал, что у меня Ubuntu

Comment: sudo apt install libtesseract-dev установливался?

Comment: @AlexAlex Устанавливал

Comment: Из терминала работает? tesseract --help

Comment: В документации не указано что это (pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd) конкретно под Windows.

Comment: @Александр В терминале он полностью функционирует и версию показывает и текст с картинки считывает. Не работает он именно в связке с pytesseract в Pycharm. Я уже и в переменную PATH пути прописал, все равно не работает

Comment: У вас значит несколько Python интерпретаторов.

Comment: У вас по этому пути (/home/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/)есть бинарники?

Comment: @Александр нет как я понял, бинарники находятся тут /home/bin/tesseract

Comment: Pyhon их ищет здесь (/home/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/)

Comment: Вам нужно это понимать.